# Oracle 10g - sql query

Tags: sql, select, count, oracle10g, sql-like

I have the following table named books

```
BookID  Title  Publisher_Name Publisher_Address No_of_Copies

select Publisher_Name from books where Title like '%C%',
```

will give me all the books conatining the letter C(in this case C Programming like ANSI C,Let Us C,etc...)

But how to solve for this:

List the publishers who have published maximum c programming books? and

List the publishers who have published less number of books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Question 1.**

```
SELECT Publisher_Name, SUM(No_of_Copies) No_of_Copies
FROM books 
WHERE Title LIKE '%C%'
GROUP BY Publisher_Name
ORDER BY No_of_Copies DESC
```

**Question 2:**

If you want List the publishers who have published less number of books of C language

```
SELECT Publisher_Name, SUM(No_of_Copies) No_of_Copies
FROM books 
WHERE Title LIKE '%C%'
GROUP BY Publisher_Name
ORDER BY No_of_Copies
```

Else for general

```
SELECT Publisher_Name, SUM(No_of_Copies) No_of_Copies
FROM books 
GROUP BY Publisher_Name
ORDER BY No_of_Copies
```

**EDIT:::**

```
SELECT Publisher_Name, SUM(No_of_Copies) No_of_Copies
FROM books 
WHERE Title LIKE '%C%'
GROUP BY Publisher_Name
ORDER BY No_of_Copies DESC LIMIT 1
```

**OR**

```
SELECT Publisher_Name, MAX(No_of_Copies) No_of_Copies
FROM (SELECT Publisher_Name, SUM(No_of_Copies) No_of_Copies
      FROM books 
      WHERE Title LIKE '%C%'
      GROUP BY Publisher_Name
      ORDER BY noOfBooks DESC
     ) AS A
```

Comment: I get the following error.SQL> select publisher_name,SUM(no_of_copies) from books where title like '%C%' g
roup by publisher_name order by no_of_copies desc;
select publisher_name,SUM(no_of_copies) from books where title like '%C%' group
by publisher_name order by no_of_copies desc

                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: @SubhamSoni Give Alias name to `SUM(no_of_copies)` as `no_of_copies` then it will work

Comment: I got it but I get output sorted in descending order of the publishers and no_of_copies.I didn't understand the query.Can u please explain?I thought i will get only a single value as output , the maximum one?

Comment: @SubhamSoni I had written a query to get list of publishers as you had mentioned in question, so that you are getting list of publishers rather than maximum no of copies

Comment: @SubhamSoni If you want maximum than you can do it by just adding `LIMIT 1` at last in query or using `MAX` function. I am adding both queries in last in my answer. So check my updated answer